# Creating an instance of type(self) dynamically without calling __init__?

Tags: python, class, copy

This is quite hard to explain. I have a class which should support the method `copy_stateonly()`. It should return a crippled version of the object which only contains the (copied) data members that I want. I hope this example explains it better:

```
# everything inherits from this
class SuperBase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state_var = 3 # this should be copied into future objects
        self.non_state_var = 0 # we don't want to copy this

    def copy_stateonly(self):
        newobj = # ??????????? create instance without calling __init__
        newobj.state_var = self.state_var
        return newobj

# some clases inherit from this
class Base(SuperBase):
    def __init__(self):
        SuperBase.__init__(self)
        self.isflying = True # we want to copy this, this is state
        self.sprite = "sprites/plane_generic.png" # we must drop this

    def copy_stateonly(self):
        newobj = SuperBase.copy_stateonly(self)
        newobj.isflying = self.isflying
        return newobj

class A144fighter(Base):
    def __init__(self, teamname): # note required __init__ argument
        Base.__init__(self)
        self.colors = ["black", "grey"] # we want to copy this, this is state
        self.name = teamname # we must drop this

    def copy_stateonly(self):
        newobj = Base.copy_stateonly(self)
        newobj.colors = self.colors[:]
        return newobj

plane = A144fighter("team_blue")
plane_state = plane.copy_stateonly() # this should return an A144fighter object with only state_var, flying and colors set.
```

Python 2.7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to create new instances of classic classes (which is what you used in your example) without calling `__init__()`.  New instances of new-style classes (descendants of `object`) can be created using

```
object.__new__(cls)
```

where `cls` is the type of object you would like to create.

An alternative is to use `copy.copy()` for copying, possibly overwriting `__getstate__()` and `__setstate__()` to define what should be copied.

**Edit**: To create a new instance of a classic class `cls` without calling `__init__()`, you can use the following hack:

```
class EmptyClass:
    pass

new_instance = EmptyClass()
new_instance.__class__ = cls
new_instance.__dict__.update(whatever)
```

Comment: no need to hack: `import types; types.InstanceType(cls)` (or `import new; new.instance(cls)`)

Comment: the second method only works when both classes have the same layout, which is true for most classes, but wont be when, for example, either class uses `__slots__`.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: As I stated, the second approach only works for *classic* classes.  `__slots__` are meaningless in this context.

Comment: Actually, that method does work even for new style classes (assuming the `EmptyClass` does indeed inherit from `object`).

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: For new-style classes it is easier to use `__new__()`, because otherwise you would have to cover many special cases (`__slots__`, built-in types among the base classes etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Remember that every object has a attribute named `__class__`. If you do `<object>.__class__` it, will return that object's class object (if that makes sense). The class object is callable so you can add parentheses to the end to create a new instance of that class.

```
newobj = self.__class__()
```

Comment: This still calls `self.__class__.__init__` - which may have required arguments as shown in the example - resulting in an error.

Comment: Ah, I thought you just didn't want to call it directly. Now, I wouldn't recommend doing this but one way you could get around this is to make all arguments optional (trust me) and add an another optional argument that is to be a boolean value. It should default to True. And you could set it to False if you don't want the "required" arguments to be required. If it's set to true, check if all the "required" variables are set (i.e. are they set to None or something else?). Again, I wouldn't recommend this.

Answer (score 2):

```
# everything inherits from this
class SuperBase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state_var = 3 # this should be copied into future objects
        self.non_state_var = 0 # we don't want to copy this

    def __getstate__(self):
        return { 'state_var' : self.state_var }

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__ + '(' + str(vars(self)) + ')'

# some clases inherit from this
class Base(SuperBase):
    def __init__(self):
        SuperBase.__init__(self)
        self.isflying = True # we want to copy this, this is state
        self.sprite = "sprites/plane_generic.png" # we must drop this

    def __getstate__(self):
        state = SuperBase.__getstate__(self)
        state['isflying'] = self.isflying
        return state

class A144fighter(Base):
    def __init__(self, teamname): # note required __init__ argument
        Base.__init__(self)
        self.colors = ["black", "grey"] # we want to copy this, this is state
        self.name = teamname # we must drop this

    def __getstate__(self):
        state = Base.__getstate__(self)
        state['colors'] = self.colors[:]
        return state

plane = A144fighter("team_blue")
print plane

import copy
print copy.copy(plane)

# or manually:
import types
print types.InstanceType(plane.__class__, plane.__getstate__())
```